# How to Make Button Merge with Border (Image Attached)

Tags: css

I would like to make box like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxiPL.png)

With The Following Requirement:

1. The Button Is Still in Border Line
2. Height is Fixed, So All The boxes Height is the same

EDIT: My Last Tried Code

**CSS**

```
.catalog {
    border: 2px solid #f0bf3c;
    height: 600px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.read-more {
    font-family: trickpony;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 9px 30px;
    background-color: #f0bf3c;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 78px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="catalog">
        <img src="http://localhost:999/img/catalog/belajar_adab_toilet.jpg">
        <center><h4>Header Title<br>Header Title</h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam suscipit condimentum gravida. Aliquam erat volutpat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed nec diam luctus, fringilla massa quis, pharetra est. Sed semper rhoncus turpis, id ullamcorper est facilisis vel. Mauris bibendum nisi sit amet pellentesque dignissim. Mauris at elit luctus, placerat sem ut, faucibus ante. Curabitur fringilla metus vel lobortis elementum. Nullam id sagittis ligula. Morbi volutpat mauris ut nunc consectetur, in mollis massa feugiat.
<br></p>
        <a href="?page=1" class="read-more">Read More</a>
    </center></div>
```

Thank You Very Much..

PS: I already tried with top, and left property but it just moved when the text is not the same as first boxes..

Comment: Please post some code that you tried

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is what you want to achieve:

```css
    .catalog {
        border: 2px solid #f0bf3c;
        height: 600px;
        width: 350px;
        margin-bottom: 65px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 25px;
        position: relative; /* to use position: absolute on .read-more */
    }

    .read-more {
        font-family: trickpony;
        height: 34px;
        line-height: 34px; /* to center text vertically */
        padding: 0 30px; /*remove top/bottom padding to keep the height of 34px */
        background-color: #f0bf3c;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        position: absolute; /* relative to catalog (position: relative) */
        bottom: -17px; /* half height (34px) */
        right: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="catalog">
        <img src="http://localhost:999/img/catalog/belajar_adab_toilet.jpg">
        <center><h4>Header Title<br>Header Title</h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam suscipit condimentum gravida. Aliquam erat volutpat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed nec diam luctus, fringilla massa quis, pharetra est. Sed semper rhoncus turpis, id ullamcorper est facilisis vel. Mauris bibendum nisi sit amet pellentesque dignissim. Mauris at elit luctus, placerat sem ut, faucibus ante. Curabitur fringilla metus vel lobortis elementum. Nullam id sagittis ligula. Morbi volutpat mauris ut nunc consectetur, in mollis massa feugiat.
<br></p>
        <a href="?page=1" class="read-more">Read More</a>
    </center></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to set `position: relative;` to `.catalog` so that
  the `absolute` button will not get out of the `.catalog`
- Set `bottom` and `right` for the `.read-more`
- You can remove unwanted `css` of `.read-more`, I have commented that
  unwanted code

```css
.catalog {
    border: 2px solid #f0bf3c;
    height: 600px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 65px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 25px;
    position: relative;
}
.read-more {
    font-family: trickpony;
    /* height: 34px; */
    padding: 9px 30px;
    background-color: #f0bf3c;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    /* margin-left: 40px; */
    /* margin-top: 78px; */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -17px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog">
        <img src="http://localhost:999/img/catalog/belajar_adab_toilet.jpg">
        <center><h4>Header Title<br>Header Title</h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam suscipit condimentum gravida. Aliquam erat volutpat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed nec diam luctus, fringilla massa quis, pharetra est. Sed semper rhoncus turpis, id ullamcorper est facilisis vel. Mauris bibendum nisi sit amet pellentesque dignissim. Mauris at elit luctus, placerat sem ut, faucibus ante. Curabitur fringilla metus vel lobortis elementum. Nullam id sagittis ligula. Morbi volutpat mauris ut nunc consectetur, in mollis massa feugiat.
<br></p>
        <a href="?page=1" class="read-more">Read More</a>
    </center></div>
```